# Como passar parâmetro SELECT DB Pervasive

Tags: sql, select, pervasive

Estou tendo que trabalhar com banco de dados Pervasive, com isso estou tendo dificuldades para passar um parâmetro para realizar um `SELECT`

Já tentei utilizando:

```
DBCmd.Parameters.Add("@inicio", PsqlDbType.VarChar).Value = date_inicio;
DBCmd.Parameters.Add("@fim", PsqlDbType.VarChar).Value = date_fim;
```

E também tentei assim:

```
DBCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inicio", "'" + date_inicio + "'");
DBCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fim", "'" + date_fim + "'");
```

Sei que por padrão do Pervasive, as datas tem que estar no formato `AAAA-MM-DD`.

Ou seja, `date_inicio` = `2016-01-01` e `date_fim` = `2016-12-31`

Segue abaixo a query:

```
SELECT a.code_client AS CODIGO, a.raison_sociale AS 'RAZÃO SOCIAL', a.Adresse_1 AS ENDEREÇO, a.Ville AS CIDADE, e.etat AS 'ESTADO', a.code_postal_siege AS CEP, a.Adresse_2 AS BAIRRO, a.Specialite_client AS SEGMENTO, 
                                CASE a.Code_representant 
                                WHEN 0 THEN 'BRAYTON'
                                WHEN 30225 THEN 'DOUGLAS'
                                WHEN 30327 THEN 'FURLAN'
                                WHEN 30431 THEN 'ALLAN'
                                WHEN 30318 THEN 'RUFINO'
                                WHEN 30140 THEN 'GURIAN'
                                END AS 'REPRESENTANTE',
                                SUM(c.montant_ht) AS 'PREÇO PROD',
                                SUM(c.montant_ht - d.vl_icms) AS 'PREÇO LIQ',
                                SUM(d.vl_ipi) AS 'VALOR IPI',
                                SUM(d.vl_icms) AS 'VALOR ICMS',
                                SUM(d.vl_pis) AS 'VALOR PIS',
                                SUM(d.vl_cofins) AS 'VALOR COFINS'
                                FROM client AS a
                                LEFT JOIN  operateur AS b
                                ON a.Code_representant = b.code
                                LEFT JOIN commande AS c
                                ON a.code_client = c.code_cl
                                LEFT JOIN BRAYTONAUX.PedidoVendaAUX AS d
                                ON c.affaire = d.cd_pedido
                                LEFT JOIN client2 AS e
                                ON a.code_client = e.code
                                WHERE c.date_creat BETWEEN CONVERT(@inicio, SQL_DATE) AND CONVERT(@fim, SQL_DATE)
                                GROUP BY a.code_client, a.raison_sociale, a.Adresse_1, a.Ville, e.etat, a.code_postal_siege, a.Adresse_2, a.Specialite_client, a.Code_representant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por padrão o Pervasive, utiliza o simbolo `?` para identificar o parâmetro, ao inves, de `@` na query.

Portanto, ficou assim:

```
SELECT a.code_client AS CODIGO, a.raison_sociale AS 'RAZÃO SOCIAL', a.Adresse_1 AS ENDEREÇO, a.Ville AS CIDADE, e.etat AS 'ESTADO', a.code_postal_siege AS CEP, a.Adresse_2 AS BAIRRO, a.Specialite_client AS SEGMENTO, 
                            CASE a.Code_representant 
                            WHEN 0 THEN 'BRAYTON'
                            WHEN 30225 THEN 'DOUGLAS'
                            WHEN 30327 THEN 'FURLAN'
                            WHEN 30431 THEN 'ALLAN'
                            WHEN 30318 THEN 'RUFINO'
                            WHEN 30140 THEN 'GURIAN'
                            END AS 'REPRESENTANTE',
                            SUM(c.montant_ht) AS 'PREÇO PROD',
                            SUM(c.montant_ht - d.vl_icms) AS 'PREÇO LIQ',
                            SUM(d.vl_ipi) AS 'VALOR IPI',
                            SUM(d.vl_icms) AS 'VALOR ICMS',
                            SUM(d.vl_pis) AS 'VALOR PIS',
                            SUM(d.vl_cofins) AS 'VALOR COFINS'
                            FROM client AS a
                            LEFT JOIN  operateur AS b
                            ON a.Code_representant = b.code
                            LEFT JOIN commande AS c
                            ON a.code_client = c.code_cl
                            LEFT JOIN BRAYTONAUX.PedidoVendaAUX AS d
                            ON c.affaire = d.cd_pedido
                            LEFT JOIN client2 AS e
                            ON a.code_client = e.code
                            WHERE c.date_creat BETWEEN CONVERT(?, SQL_DATE) AND CONVERT(?, SQL_DATE)
                            GROUP BY a.code_client, a.raison_sociale, a.Adresse_1, a.Ville, e.etat, a.code_postal_siege, a.Adresse_2, a.Specialite_client, a.Code_representant
```

Sendo a declaração de parâmetros assim:

```
DBCmd.Parameters.Add("@inicio", PsqlDbType.Date).Value = date_inicio;
DBCmd.Parameters.Add("@fim", PsqlDbType.Date).Value = date_fim;
```